# Identify maximum distance element from String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I have a requirement where I have to find an element from an array that has maximum distance in occurrence.

If there are two terms that were equally searched, the return term has the longest distance between when it was first and last searched.
Given the following array
[‘C++’, ‘Java’, ‘C#’, ‘C#’, ‘Java’, ‘Python’, ‘C#’, ‘Java’]
Our Program should return “Most searched term is Java”

Note: Both ‘Java’ and ‘C#’ were searched 3 times, but the program should return ‘Java’ as distance
between its first and last search is greater than that of ‘C#’.

I tried searching, I can find the distance (6) but couldn't return the value (Java).

Thank you so much everyone for your input. I did this successfully in JS. I was only looking for Java help. I can post my JS code.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly show your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Wou {
public static int main(String args[]) {
    String s = "";
    for(String x: args)
        s+=x;
    int h = 0, p = -1;    //p is for storing distance and h is for maximum distance between two strings in String 's'.
    String word = "";
    int len = args.length;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        int cc = s.lastIndexOf(args[i])-s.indexOf(args[i]);
        if (cc>h){
            h = cc;
            for(int j=len-1;j>=0;j--)
                if(args[i]==args[j]) {
                    p = j-i;
                    break;
                }
            word = args[i];
        }
        s.replaceAll(args[i],"");
    }
    System.out.println("Most searched term is "+word);
    return p;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which I tried -

```
    String[] a ={"C++", "Java", "C#", "C#", "Java", "Python", "C#", "Java"};
    String val ="";
    
     int maxDist = 0;
       for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
       {
          int firstOcc = -1;
          int lastOcc = -1;
          
          for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
          {
             if(a[i] == a[j])
             {
                 //val=a[j];
                 if(firstOcc == -1)
                   firstOcc = lastOcc = j;
                 //val=a[j];
             }
                else
                {
                   lastOcc = j;
                 val=a[j];
             }
          }
          if(lastOcc - firstOcc > maxDist)
             maxDist = lastOcc - firstOcc;
            
       }
       System.out.println("Most searched term is " + val);
}
```

Comment: Put the code in the question please not as an answer. And make sure it appears formatted correctly